# How to center Crop HD images whose width is greater

Tags: html, image, css

i am using this to crop but this is not working properly for wider images, but work perfectly for those images whose height is greater.

```
 border:1px solid black;
 background: url(http://www.hdwallpaper201.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Rajnikanth-Sketch-HD-Photo.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center / 100% auto transparent;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 left: 717px;
 top: 646px;
 z-index: auto;
```

[Fiddle Link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4m9c4c67/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `background-size: cover`

```css
.bg {
 border:1px solid black;
 background: url(http://www.hdwallpaper201.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Rajnikanth-Sketch-HD-Photo.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center / 100% auto transparent;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 left: 717px;
 top: 646px;
 z-index: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```